# Microprocessor Power Relay

Tags: power, relay

Beginning Electrical Engineering student here and had a basic question. I am researching microprocessor based relays and came upon the SEL-351 relay for differential over current. Looking at the spec sheet, it shows the following functional overview:

[image]

My question is, when this relay is put into a protection scheme, does this spec sheet mean that this relay will protect with all of the following scenarios below (67 P/G/Q, 27, etc) or are the features selectable, as in the user can select particular features to enable?

Comment: A lazy boy link would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to SEL and since these are microprocessor based relays, the features are selectable depending on the protection scheme you would like.

Answer (score 0):

The correct person to answer this question is the manufacturer, Selinc. When asking for help, it is always helpful to include a link to the: [DATASHEET](https://www.selinc.com/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=226)

I have never heard of these devices but they are very neat. Their telephone number is 1.509.332.1890 in Pullman, Washington, USA. Don't be hesitant to call them up.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was more of a general question, but never thought of contacting them before. I will do just that.

Comment: And that way, if you get the answer you were looking for, you should be able to report it on this site so now that information will be on the internet!

Comment: Yes, definitely will. Looks like I cannot up vote answers as of yet due to being new, but once I do get some information I will post here. Thanks.